# Is it possible to position second generated Div after third Div

Tags: php, html, css

Ok, so I really don't know if it's possible but I believe that must be a work around as always! What I want to achieve:

got something like:

```
<div id="one">
   HEADER pph content...
</div>

<div id="two">
   BOTTOM php content...
</div>

<div id="three">
   BODY php content...
</div>
```

I what to place the div number two beneath the (auto-size) div number three!

The problem is that the div number two gets generated first. than div number three and I can't get it to work as I want...

Appreciated your help.
Regards.

Comment: "the div number two gets generated first than div number two" ?

Comment: I think you’re a bit confused. Don’t you mean you want to position `<div id="two">` after `<div id="three">`>?

Comment: it is hard to guess if you are talking about HTML, PHP, CSS or a mix. As Cristian noted, your question makes little sense as it is. If that is the html you want to get, could you post what you have got so far and the relevant CSS or PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap all three divs in a relatively positioned div, then you can absolutely position the "bottom" div at the bottom, it will work better if you are able to approximate the height of the bottom div so you can apply the same amount of padding to the bottom of the wrapper to create space for it

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
  width: 700px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  background: #eee; 
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 5em;
}

#two {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5%;
  background: #ffe;
  width: 90%;
  height: 5em;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="one">
   HEADER pph content...
</div>
<div id="two">
   BOTTOM php content...
</div>
<div id="three">
   BODY php content...
</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Update re: comments

Here's a version that doesn't need any heights or bottom  padding, only works if nothing follows the "footer"

I put it in a jsfiddle, so you can tweak

#### JSFiddle Example: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/kPZ22/)

with this version `#two` is still absolutely positioned but rather than guess at the height it becomes a 1px high placeholder, the actual content will then overflow below `#two` and therefore the main content - `#three` - you need to ensure div#two (footer) has a child div inside it, again just add it into your php template, then you can style it as you wish, it should take a min-height if you still need that, but this way should just work, if you need white-space below this for any reason you would add `padding-bottom` to the `body` element e.g.

```
body {padding-bottom: 10em;}
```

this div (#two) is no longer "contained" in the wrapper element, though it still needs it to take it's position from

---

Comment: that's plain old CSS ;) -  You should be able to generate the wrapper div with PHP (opening tag in your header php, closing in your footer.php) as well.. it doesn't matter how HTML is generated, CSS can be applied to it whatever

Comment: Ok, so this is generated by php... the generating order must be like: one, two, three... that is because the body content some of the times gets a lot to be generated and the div number two would be generated after which causes the a very annoying effect. The problem is that the div where body content goes has to be min-size:px (auto-resizable) and therefore I can't predict the the position of div number two!

Comment: that's why it's attached to the bottom of the wrapper div, the wrapper itself will grow with the content, and the bottom won't be known until the main content is generated.,. the CSS will still position the second one at the bottom after the content is rendered - have you tried it?

Comment: You're Welcome! as you're new remember if the answer helped, don't forget to click the tick, and/or upvote ;)

Comment: Ok so there is a little issue... the bottom div has to be height fix! If I give something like min-height: 30px than I get unexpected behavior how can i manage this?

Comment: like I said in my answer it will work better with a height, but if you give the height in em's, so the bottom padding can bge matched to it - providing of course that the bottom content height is somewhat consistent, it should look OK.. failing that a change in the source order shouldn't be difficult if you just sway the php templates

Comment: I have swapped and tested your solution 5 hrs ago, works great. The problem is that the bottom is fixed height. both divs (body and bottom) doesn't touch each other, there is a fixed space between them, and the bottom div can sometimes be smaller that is why I would like the bottom div to be min-height: 25px or so...

Comment: You can't set the bottom padding on the wrapper to be a min-padding though so it won't work for that use case, hang on.. I think there might be another way.. it might be even hackier though ;)

Comment: @FCC-PT OK .. I have one important question, after this there's no answer without Javascript ;).. is there any content to be displayed after div #two (the bottom content) .. I have a solution that is not height dependant but it won't work if there's anything after the bottom div

Comment: lol.. Ok then I've updated the answer with a jsfiddle at the bottom showing the "new" (well slightly updated) version